# Trying passing as a paramater two dimesional array In C

Tags: c

When I am trying to pass  two dimensional array as a parameter In C,

```
void PrintTriangle(int *triangle)
```

It's doesn't works for me why ?

Comment: How you called `printTriangle`? Posting your code/snippet may help us to answer this question.

Comment: What isn't working?  Please provide details: how you passed in the array, what you tried to do in printTriangle and how it failed.

Comment: @haccks int pascalTriangle[5][5];
pascalTriangle[0][0] = 1;
PrintTriangle(pascalTriangle);

Comment: Read: [c++ dynamic array initalization with declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17567663/1673391)

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the dimension of the outermost array when passing multidimensional arrays as parameters

Something like this:-

```
void PrintTriangle(int pascalTriangle[][5]);
```

Calling `PrintTriangle(pascalTriangle);` like this is wrong as your function `PrintTriangle()` is expecting a pointer to integer.

Comment: so how do you specify the dimension ?

Comment: @haccks:- The reason why it is wrong is very similar to what you mentioned. Still updated that in my answer!!! Thanx!! :)

Comment: Also read the comments to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18661858/2455888).

Comment: The last dimension is for the innermost array, not outermost. In `int a[2][3]`, `a[i]` is an aggregate object that is an array of three `int`. So arrays corresponding to the last dimension are inside the arrays of previous dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your function as

```
 PrintTriangle(pascalTriangle);
```

is wrong. Because `PrintTriangle()` expecting a *pointer to integer* as its argument and `pascalTriangle` (after decaying) is of type `int(*)[5]`.Also you must have to [pass the number of rows and columns (as arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18661858/2455888) in array `pascalTriangle`. Prototype for this function should be

```
void PrintTriangle(int row, int col, int *triangle);
```

and a call to it may be

```
PrintTriangle(5, 5, &pascalTriangle[0][0]);
```

Comment: @H2CO3; Ya. I know, and you know what that mean in fact :)

Comment: I only encourage you to use the correct wording, which now you do :)

Comment: You're welcome, don't take it as nitpicking when I'm correcting something minor in what you wrote. I often do this to people only in order to save them from potential mass-downvoting :P and for the sake of learning, in first place.

Comment: C does not require you to pass the number of rows and columns of a two-dimensional array, just the number of columns. (The called function might require it for other reasons.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Read comments to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18661858/2455888).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I memorized passing multidemensional arrays as parameters. This might be a little childish but works for me.
Suppose You have an array defined

```
int numbers[3][4];
```

and you want to pass it to function.
To do it correctly I answer series of questions:
1) What do I want to pass to function? An array.(in this case `numbers`).
2) What's `numbers`? `Numbers` is an address of its first element(without going into details);
3)What's the `first element of numbers`?(in this case it's an `array of 4 integers`)
4) So what I want as function formal parameter is a `pointer to answer from step 3`:

```
int  (*pointer)[4]
```

It might be slow and looks unprofessional but you can ask the same question on array of every dimension you can think of. It's also useful to ask yourself that when not passing whole array but one of subarrays.
Hope it helps you as it helped me.

Comment: You can simple declare the parameter the same way the array is declared: `void foo(int numbers[3][4]);`. The compiler will automatically adjust it to `int (*numbers)[4]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as I mentioned, it's not fast nor smart, just something that I used when learned about multidimensional arrays myself.Helped me to understand pointers and arrays of any size better. Also, it leaves almost no place for silly mistakes.